# Read-only Namespace in Python

Tags: python, namespaces

What does read-value mean in the context of names?

```
In [1]: def outer():
   ...:     x=1
   ...:     def inner():
   ...:         print x
   ...:     inner()
   ...:

In [2]: outer()
1
```

Like in the above example x in not the namespace of `inner()`. Do variables in namespaces have types such as read-only/ writeable etc?

> Quoting official docs: "To rebind variables found outside of the innermost
>   scope, the nonlocal statement can be used; if not declared nonlocal,
>   those variable are read-only (an attempt to write to such a variable
>   will simply create a new local variable in the innermost scope,
>   leaving the identically named outer variable unchanged)."

Reference: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces (5 th last paragraph)

Answer (score 3):

No, variables don't have 'properties' like read-only or write. The *namespace implementation* may disallow direct manipulation, but that's something entirely different.

The `nonlocal` and `global` statements let you override the scope of a variable; without these Python will make a name *local* if it is being *bound* to.  Binding actions include assignment, `for` loop, `with .. as` and `except .. as` statement targets, function arguments and imports. Changing the scope doesn't alter if a variable is read-only or not, it merely changes the scope that manages the variable. `nonlocal` means it'll be stored in a parent scope and made a closure.

The term *read-only* used by the quote you found is *very misleading*; assignment clearly still alters the local variable. The presence of local doesn't make the same name in the parent scope not writable, it is simply *not visible* in the innermost scope. It's disappointing that this is from the official tutorials; I've [reported a bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue26449) to see this corrected.

Comment: I have trouble fitting together the namespace and read-only. Are you saying namespaces are only relevant for binding?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: there is no such thing as read-only. The quote you found is very misleading. I'm disappointed that this is from the Python tutorial.

Comment: Thanks! Are there good references to what happens what variable is read. What is the order of scope followed then. Check edit in question for cause of confusion.

Comment: See [Short Description of Python Scoping Rules](http://stackoverflow.com/q/291978) for the scope rules.

Comment: The warning is entirely unrelated. It is better to put the `global x` statement first in a function, so anyone reading the code sees it first. Because it affects the *whole* scope it doesn't really matter where you put it in the function.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense.

Comment: I am not sure if I understand what you mean by "nonlocal means it'll be stored in a parent scope and made a closure." To me in the example, `x` is already in the closure of `inner()`. What has `non-local` got to do with it?

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: you didn't assign to `x`, so yes, it'll be a non-local (a closure) by default. But if you tried to assign to it in `inner()`, but want to keep it a non-local, you need to mark it as such explicitly.

Comment: On the same page in foot-note : `Except for one thing. Module objects have a secret read-only attribute called __dict__ which returns the dictionary used to implement
the module’s namespace; the name __dict__ is an attribute but not a global name. ` It seems to state read-only again.

Comment: @AbhishekBhatia: that's because the **attribute** is read-only. You cannot replace it. You can't do `import module; module.__dict__ = something_else`. Attributes are not variables in the sense of scoping rules.